# Google CSE integration not working when using paid version's API key

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I created a proof of concept using Google Custom Search Engine. I'm using the following C# library for that: Google.Apis.Customsearch.v1

The concept was working and accepted by the customer. The customer then upgraded to the paid version of Google CSE: Google Site Search.

But when using the API key provided in the panel of the paid version, I get the following error:

```
{“Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nInvalid Value [400]\r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[Invalid Value] Location[ – ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]\r\n]\r\n”}
```

The API key in that panel seems to be a public key, you can actually find it on numerous websites.

We can only get it working again, by using our own project key we created at https://console.developers.google.com. This comes with a 100 request/day limitation, unless you also go for the paid option here (making it a double expense).

Is it at all possible to make this work with this library AND the paid version of Google CSE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Site Search and Google Site Search API are two different things.

To use the API you need a key created on google developers console. The quota associated with the key is the quota for the Google developer account Not the user that has authenticated the application.

Now they upgraded there Google sites search which means they should have some kind of support with that. I suggest they contact google and see if they can get a google developer project upgraded as well they will have to create there own project and will no longer be able to use yours.   I have never tried to my knowledge they are separate and you have to pay for them separately but it wont hurt for them to contact Google and ask.

Comment: I actually managed to get it working. By getting the source code for that library, I could debug and capture the request sent to Google's CSE API. I noticed that my keys were encoded.